# Problem select and deselecting ranges of checkboxes

Tags: javascript, datatables

I have a page that will have 4 separate datatables on the page. Each table will have a select/deselect all button. I am trying to get this working with only two tables so far. When I click the buttons it changes the button value from Select All to Deselect All and so on, but when I am on the first groups table and click the button nothing happens for the groups. The schedule records all get selected. Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

```
<script>

var checkflag = "false";

function checkGroups() {
  var inputs = document.getElementsByClassName( 'group' );
  if (checkflag == "false")
   {
  for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
      inputs.checked = true;
    }
    checkflag = "true";
    return "Deselect All";
    }
else {
  for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++)
  {
  inputs.checked = false; }
  checkflag = "false";
  return "Select All";
  }
}

var checkflag2 = "false";

function checkGroups() {
  var inputs2 = document.getElementsByClassName( 'schedule' );
  if (checkflag2 == "false")
   {
  for (var i = 0; i < inputs2.length; i++) {
      inputs2.checked = true;
    }
    checkflag2 = "true";
    return "Deselect All";
    }
else {
  for (var i = 0; i < inputs2.length; i++)
  {
  inputs2.checked = false; }
  checkflag2 = "false";
  return "Select All";
  }
}

</script>

<div class="card-body">
  <div class="card-datatable table-responsive">
  <table id="request-list" class="table table-striped " style="border-style: none; ">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th></th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <cfloop query="grouplist">
      <tr>
        <td>
          <label class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
            <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input group" value="#id#" name="group" id="group">
              <span class="custom-control-label">#displayname#</span>
          </label>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </cfloop>
  </table>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="card-body">
  <div class="card-datatable table-responsive">
  <table id="schedule-list" class="table table-striped " style="border-style: none; ">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th></th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <cfloop query="schedulelist">
      <tr>
        <td>
          <label class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
            <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input schedule" value="#id#" name="schedule" id="schedule">
              <span class="custom-control-label">#displayname#</span>
          </label>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </cfloop>
  </table>
  </ul>
</div>

<script>

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#request-list').DataTable( {
        "dom": '<"toolbar">frtip',
        "iDisplayLength": 500
    } );
    $("div.toolbar").html('<input class="btn btn-primary btn-sm md-btn-flat ml-3 checkall" type="button" name="CheckAll" id="checkall" value="Select All" onClick="this.value=checkGroups(this.form)" style="float:left;">');
} );


$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#schedule-list').DataTable( {
        "dom": '<"toolbar">frtip',
        "iDisplayLength": 500
    } );
    $("div.toolbar").html('<input class="btn btn-primary btn-sm md-btn-flat ml-3 checkall2" type="button" name="CheckAll2" id="checkall2" value="Select All" onClick="this.value=checkScheds(this.form)" style="float:left;">');
} );


</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few issues with the code you have shared.

**Issues**

1. checkScheds method is missing. You have named both methods as checkGroups
2. When you call the `$("div.toolbar").html` second time it actually replace all the `div` elements in the page with class `toolbar`
3. You rather need to attach the 1st click handler with the first toolbar inside request-list and second with the second toolbar inside the schedule-list
4. When you call `DataTable` it actually adds the wrapper divs like `request-list_wrapper` and `schedule-list_wrapper`
5. So you have to actually using the selector `#request-list_wrapper div.toolbar` when you call `.html` method
6. Furthermore in the `checkGroups` and `checkScheds` methods inside the for loops you have to set `inputs[i].checked` to access the individual checkboxes rather than `inputs.checked`

**Working Solution 1**

You can have a look at the following code snippet that is working fine.

```js
var checkflag = false;

function checkGroups() {

  var inputs = document.getElementsByClassName( 'group' );
  
  checkflag = checkflag === false ? true : false;
  
  for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
      inputs[i].checked = checkflag;
    }
    
  return checkflag === true ? "Deselect All" : "Select All";
}

var checkflag2 = false;

function checkScheds() {
  
  var inputs = document.getElementsByClassName( 'schedule' );
  
  checkflag2 = checkflag2 === false ? true : false;
  
  for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
      inputs[i].checked = checkflag2;
    }
    
  return checkflag2 === true ? "Deselect All" : "Select All";
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#request-list').DataTable( {
        "dom": '<"toolbar">frtip',
        "iDisplayLength": 500
    } );
    $("#request-list_wrapper div.toolbar").html('<input class="btn btn-primary btn-sm md-btn-flat ml-3 checkall" type="button" name="CheckAll" id="checkall" value="Select All" onClick="this.value=checkGroups(this.form)" style="float:left;">');
} );


$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#schedule-list').DataTable( {
        "dom": '<"toolbar">frtip',
        "iDisplayLength": 500
    } );
    $("#schedule-list_wrapper div.toolbar").html('<input class="btn btn-primary btn-sm md-btn-flat ml-3 checkall2" type="button" name="CheckAll2" id="checkall2" value="Select All" onClick="this.value=checkScheds(this.form)" style="float:left;">');
} );
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="//cdn.datatables.net/1.11.3/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.11.3/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>


<div class="card-body">
  <div class="card-datatable table-responsive">
  <table id="request-list" class="table table-striped " style="border-style: none; ">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th></th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <cfloop query="grouplist">
      <tr>
        <td>
          <label class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
            <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input group" value="#id#" name="group" id="group">
              <span class="custom-control-label">#displayname#</span>
          </label>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </cfloop>
  </table>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="card-body">
  <div class="card-datatable table-responsive">
  <table id="schedule-list" class="table table-striped " style="border-style: none; ">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th></th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <cfloop query="schedulelist">
      <tr>
        <td>
          <label class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
            <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input schedule" value="#id#" name="schedule" id="schedule">
              <span class="custom-control-label">#displayname#</span>
          </label>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </cfloop>
  </table>
  </ul>
</div>
```

**Working Solution 2**

Another version of the solution is [this](https://jsfiddle.net/muasif80/omu2v36b/121/).

Comment: Thank you for explaining this to me! I didn't know that the datatable divs were all being replaced. This works great!